# Python: Getting Blank HostName with UrlParse

Tags: python, pandas, urlparse

I'm using Python 2.7 and have a Pandas dataframe with a column called `url`.  I'm trying to extract the domain as follows:

```
def get_hostname(url):
    return urlparse(url).netloc
```

When I try this on `'http://www.ocolly.com/news/article'`, I get back:

```
'www.ocolly.com'
```

Perfect.

Now, I try:

```
df['url_hostname'] = df['url'].apply(get_hostname)
```

Then I look at `df.head()` and all of my rows have blank `url_hostname` columns.  Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: it should works. what return `print (df['url'].apply(get_hostname))` ?  Also `def get_hostname(url): print (urlparse(url).netloc)` works?

Comment: When I do `print (df['url'].apply(get_hostname))`, I get back `0       
1       
2       
3       
4       
5       
6...`

Comment: so no strings? maybe it return emty strings only

Comment: @jezrael It definitely gives me a Series of empty strings, I just don't understand why :(

Comment: Hmmm, I think there is some problem with data in `url` column. Maybe some traling whitespaces? Then use `print (df['url'].str.strip().apply(get_hostname))`

Comment: @jezrael Same as before, just a Series of numbers in order...

Comment: idea - try `print (df['url'].tolist()[:10])` and check if not soething wrong.